# service discovery in tcl

Tags: tcl, cross-platform, service-discovery, zeroconf

I'm writing a little Tcl/Tk script, that uses a (custom) web-application (written in Python) to retrieve information from some central storage.

Everything works nicely, but only as long as the address of the webserver is known beforehand.

So I thought about adding some kind of service discovery, where my script would discover all running instances of my web-application on the local network, and automatically use them.

My first idea was to use Zeroconf/Bonjour/Avahi, and have my web-application publish a `_my-web-service._tcp` service with the actual query path (that the tcl client script should use to access the data) encoded in the `TXT` field:

```bash
avahi-publish-service MyService _my-web-service._tcp 8000 path=/data
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found *anything* that brings zeroconf-like service-discovery into the Tcl-world.

In particular, I was looking at the [DNS entry on the Tcl Wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/DNS) but that only gets me as far as `mDNS` (and i currently have no clue how to proceed from there to zeroconf stack).

I'm not especially bound to Zeroconf/Bonjour/Avahi, but would like to run my script on Linux/Windows/macOS, *and* keep my build requirements minimal (that is: i would prefer it, if i don't have to compile my own wrapper code to interface with the service-discovery for each platform). Telling the users to install Bonjour or whatnot from 3rd-party sources would be tolerable though.

Comment: Is there a command-line tool to read this information?  If so you could just `exec` it from Tcl and read the output.

Comment: I found https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Bonjour but I don't know how helpful that is. There isn't much due to the weakness of UDP support, and that in turn stems from long-standing arguments over what an API for such message-oriented comms should be. Tcl's standard channel support is *very* team-oriented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In particular, I was looking at the DNS entry on the Tcl Wiki but that
> only gets me as far as mDNS (and i currently have no clue how to
> proceed from there to zeroconf stack).

You were looking at the right corner, but the code snippet at the [Tcl'ers Wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/DNS) appears outdated. I was curious and gave it some love.

This was tested using:

```
% package req Tcl
8.6.12
% package req dns
1.4.1
% package req udp
1.0.11
```

... and by announcing an exemplary service on macOS via:

```
dns-sd -R "Index" _http._tcp . 80 path=/index22.html
```

I managed to discover the above service using the patched `dns` package, by retrieving the DNS-SD (RFC 6763) specific records, mainly the target and port from the `SRV` record(s), and extras (e.g., a path) from the corresponding `TXT` record(s):

```
set instanceName "Index._http._tcp.local"
set tok [::dns::resolve $instanceName -protocol mdns -type SRV]
if {[::dns::wait $tok] eq "ok"} {

  set res [dict create {*}[lindex [::dns::result $tok] 0]]; # Pick first answer record, only!
  array set SRV [dict get $res rdata]
  ::dns::cleanup $tok
  
  
  set tok [::dns::resolve $instanceName -protocol mdns -type TXT]
  if {[::dns::wait $tok] eq "ok"} {
    array set TXT {}
    foreach txt [::dns::result $tok] {
      lassign [split [dict get $txt rdata] "="] k v
      set TXT($k) $v
    }
    ::dns::cleanup $tok
  }

  set tok [::dns::resolve $SRV(target) -protocol mdns -type A]
  if {[::dns::wait $tok] eq "ok"} {
    set res [dict create {*}[lindex [::dns::result $tok] 0]]; # Pick first answer record, only!
    puts "Service IP: [dict get $res rdata]"
    puts "Service port: $SRV(port)"
    puts "Service options: [array get TXT]"
  }
  ::dns::cleanup $tok
}
```

This will print:

```
Service IP: 192.168.0.14
Service port: 80
Service options: path /index222.html
```

---

## Patching tcllib's `dns`

The snippet from [Tcl'ers Wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/DNS) needs to be modified, yielding:

```
proc ::dns::UdpTransmit {token} {
  # FRINK: nocheck
  variable $token
  upvar 0 $token state

  # setup the timeout
  if {$state(-timeout) > 0} {
    set state(after) [after $state(-timeout) \
                          [list [namespace origin reset] \
                               $token timeout\
                               "operation timed out"]]
  }
  
  if {[llength [package provide ceptcl]] > 0} {
    # using ceptcl
    set state(sock) [cep -type datagram $state(-nameserver) $state(-port)]
    chan configure $state(sock) -blocking 0
  } else {
    # using tcludp
    set state(sock) [udp_open]
    if { $state(-protocol) eq "mdns" } {
      set state(-nameserver) "224.0.0.251"
      set state(-port)       5353
      chan configure $state(sock) -mcastadd $state(-nameserver);
    }
  }
  chan configure $state(sock) -remote [list $state(-nameserver) $state(-port)] \
      -translation binary \
      -buffering none;
  
  set state(status) connect
  chan event $state(sock) readable [list [namespace current]::UdpEvent $token]
  puts -nonewline $state(sock) $state(request)
  
  return $token
}
```

Background:

- This is mainly to reflect changes to `udp` API (`udp_conf` is replaced by `chan configure /socket/ -remote`)
- ... but also: the original snippet does not join the multicast IP to listen for the mDNS responses (`-mcastadd`).
- Other than that, `dns` is capable of decoding the DNS resource records (SRV, TXT) etc. just fine.

> (that is: i would prefer it, if i don't have to compile my own wrapper
> code to interface with the service-discovery for each platform)

This way, you do not have to interface with any third-party library or `exec` to some executable (`dns-sd`), but you will have to bundle your Tcl/Tk script with the platform-specific TclUDP extension, as a starpack or starkit, maybe?

Comment: TclUDP is well maintained and available for Win, macOS, and Linux; including starkit/ starpack generators like LUCK or Kitcreator. I used Wireshark to monitor the UDP traffic, all seems fine from down under.

Comment: wow. and for completeness sake: `::dns::resolve _my-web-service._tcp.local -protocol mdns -type PTR` will list all services announcing `_my-web-service._tcp.local`

Comment: i've submitted this to the [TclLib tracker](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/tktview/294ebffb63ea83f340dd91303303c071f2de497c) - hope this is ok for you...

Comment: just noticed that querying the `PTR` record will only return results from localhost (and not from other servers, even though they can be queried explicitely if you know their "name", as you have shown); bummer.

Comment: ah, it's much more complicated (of course). it seems as if `::dns` will just return after it receives the first result (which i think is a good strategy in an ordinary DNS setup), but with mDNS the other hosts might be late to the party (`localhost` will most likely be the fastest responder; but if there are multiple remote services and no local one, the winner is just random....)

Comment: I haven't tested but you could try using a callback command ([`-command`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-19/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/dns/tcllib_dns.html#1) flag) plus `dns::wait` to have `dns::resolve` hanging-in for additional DNS-SD responses?